# JTextPane only set character attributes correctly in the first line

Tags: java, swing

I´m making a text editor in Java for training purposes. So, I´m using JTextPane to edit the text and setCharacterAttributes to highlight some words in the text. The code works partially, in the first line everything works, but then in the second line and forth the code stops to work. The code bellow shows my attempt to fix this bug:

```
        private void changeColor(StyledDocument styledDocument)
        {
            String keywords[] = {"html", "body", "div", "teste"};
            String texto      = edtEditing.getText();

            int startIndex;
            int start;

            StyleContext context = StyleContext.getDefaultStyleContext();

            Style styleDefault = context.getStyle(StyleContext.DEFAULT_STYLE); // default
            styledDocument.setCharacterAttributes(0, texto.length(), styleDefault, true);

            AttributeSet attr = context.addAttribute(context.getEmptySet(), StyleConstants.Foreground, Color.red);

            for (String word:keywords)
            {
                startIndex = 0;
                start      = texto.indexOf(word, startIndex);
                while (start >= 0)
                {
                    styledDocument.setCharacterAttributes(start, word.length(), attr, true);
                    startIndex += word.length();
                    start = texto.indexOf(word, startIndex);
                }
            }
        }
```

See the error on the image bellow:
[Click to see the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JKnaW.png)

The erros seems to occurs because of CRLF but I cannot figure out why...

Here is the [executable jar file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B70lhrcHXKYVUl9hZHBxOWNWT2s/view?usp=sharing). Just select File->New and type "teste"
Thanks in advance!

Comment: what's the error ?

Comment: Type "teste" in the first line, it´s ok, hit enter and type "teste" again, you will see the error. Only "este" will be highlighted, hit enter again then only "ste" will be highlighted... The only difference I see is that  the line feed is not being handled correctly by the component.

Comment: i can't find out the problem of you code using `jar` file , tell me when you hit the `teste` again what happens ?

Comment: Added an image, so you can see the error. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This side-effect is caused by this line:

```
String texto      = edtEditing.getText();
```

You're getting your text directly from the `JTextPane`, but you're setting your attributes on a `StyledDocument` object. Change this line to:

```
StyledDocument document = edtEditing.getStyledDocument();
String texto = document.getText(0, document.getLength());
```

And handle the possible exception.

You can run the code below to see that this behavior is consistent, and contrary to one might expect, a "false" will be printed.

```
JTextPane pane = new JTextPane();
pane.setText("Something html\r\nSomething html");
StyledDocument document = pane.getStyledDocument();
String text2 = pane.getText();
String text1 = document.getText(0, document.getLength());
System.out.println(text1.equals(text2));
```

Comment: Glad to help :) You can mark the answer as accepted so that other users will see that your question was resolved before they enter it.